Images without width/height attributes cause visual glitch during load
I'm facing an issue with image loading on my website. My images do not have width and height attributes specified, so there's no space allocated for them while they load. This is causing a visual glitch where the layout shifts as the images load in.
<img src="sampleimage.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="An image"> <-- no width and height attributes

Currently, I'm using width: 100% in my CSS to make the images responsive.
CSS:
img {
   width: 100%;
}

The width: 100% makes the image responsive, which I like, but as I mentioned earlier, there's no space allocated for the image when it initially loads.
Would it be better to assign the original width and height attributes to the image?
<img src="sampleimage.jpg" loading="lazy" width="800" height="600" alt="An image">

The width and height values are larger than the container that will hold the image, but I can manage to fix the issue by using height: auto.
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

My question at this point is: Adding the width and height attributes is a good idea regardless, right? even if the width and height are larger than the container that holds the image on the website, it’s still okay to add the original width and height of the image, right? I mean this:
<div class="image-container"> <--- this container is only 400px in width
 <img src="sampleimage.jpg" loading="lazy" width="800" height="600" alt="An image">
</div>

but using this makes it look good:

img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}


I've noticed that there is another CSS propery called max-inline-size. Is that something new? I think I can replace:
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

with
img {
  max-inline-size: 100%;
  block-size: auto;
}

to achieve the same. Any pros and cons between them?

Too many questions, but on your principal one, that's what the height and width attributes are for.

Isn't this a website to ask questions?

Avoid asking supplemental questions. Create a new question with an appropriate title, description etc instead, so that people with the same query can find it.

If .image-container has a fixed width and height there shouldn't be any shifting.

The glitching on image elements without a width and height is intended behavior. I would recommend using the width and height attributes in addition to the CSS. Since max-inline-size: 100%; currently works in all modern browsers according to caniuse I see no problem in using it if it gives the correct result.
